# Installation script blocked by antivirus

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.1 instance on my development machine. But the script is being blocked by antivirus. The powershell window just closes after it is blocked. It does not show any errors.

[image]

Below are the last few lines in the log -

```
[---------------------------------------------------------------------XConnectXP0_CleanShards : Command-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
[ShardingTool - Clean]:[Path] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\agnlocal.xconnect\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe
[-------------------------------------------------------------------- ConnectXP0_CreateShards : Command-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
[ShardingTool - Create]:[Path] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\agnlocal.xconnect\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe
```

Please suggest how to install.

Comment: Can you try disabling antivirus before installation process?

Comment: We are not allowed to disable antivirus as per company rules. Can you please suggest any other way?

Comment: What you can do is work with the security team to provide exclusions for specific files and directories.

Comment: Thanks. Did the same. Installation is done now.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of issues can be easily overridden by using virtual machines (VM). This is one of the reasons why I am using VMs and not installing Sitecore, Visual Studio, SQL Server  and other apps directly on my laptop's OS.

Hyper-V technology build directly into Windows was causing me trouble when on Wifi and I couldn't override settings because of company rules.

That's why I strongly suggest to use Oracle's [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) as your virtualization tool.

You need to have laptop with at least 16 GB of RAM so you can assign at least 10 gigs to your VM to make Sitecore work as smooth as possible.